# Issue installing metagpt on Python 3.11 on Windows

Tags: python, pip, package

I receives this error when trying to install metagpt packages:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\anthony phan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python311\\lib\\site-packages\\metagpt-0.1-py3.11.egg'
```

I already find in Task manager but cannot find what program is using it
I Remove the whole clone and reclone it
Uninstall and reinstall Python
Delete app data for pip

Answer (score 0):

1. try to delete the file 'metagpt-0.1-py3.11.egg', and try again.
2. if still not work , you can use `pip install -r requirements.txt` instead of `python setup.py`